# How to encode HTML string in Cocos Creator?

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js, cocoscreator

Normally we should encode user input strings before displaying to avoid execution of malicious code. like this:

```
var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
```

But how is it possible in Cocos Creator? Or it is not necessary and is taken care of by default? Thanks.

Comment: This is a very interesting question, upvoted right away. I have not tried such a thing out. But did you attempt to try to run malicious code in a Cocos Game to see how it behaves?

Answer (score 0):

create a function like this, you may change console.log to return function, it's only return content of html elemenent, result will only "Hello world".

```
let div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "<div>Hello world</div>";
console.log(div.innerText);
```